# how to filter json correctly with HttpClient angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i am having problem migrating from Http to HttpClient, this is the code that i use

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: HttpClient, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

 this.http.get('http://example.com/date.php')
.subscribe(data => {
  this.posts = data;
  this.postsfilter = data.filter(item => item.date == todayDate);

 });

 }
```

i have included import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'; but still getting error : Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'. how to filter the return json file correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `data.filter()` you will access the `Array.prototype.filter()` method and not the RxJS's filter method. In your case, `data` contains an object which does not have a method `filter`. That's causing the error.

To use RxJS's filter you need to chain it to your `Observable` with the `.` notation.

That's how it looks like:

```
 this.http.get('http://example.com/date.php')
  .map(item => this.postsfilter = item)
  .filter(item => item.date === todayDate) // probably you would also want to go for strict equality
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.posts = data;
  });
```

> Notice: Since RxJS 5.5 you are able to use the `pipe` method. THis basically changes the way you chain RxJS operators. Learn more about it here: https://blog.hackages.io/rxjs-5-5-piping-all-the-things-9d469d1b3f44

Comment: thanks for answering, i need both this.post and this.postsfilter. how can i use Array.prototype.filter(). because if i use method above i will have to call http.get twice. i want to filter it in ts file

Comment: @jx1986 you could use the map operator to assign the unfiltered value to `this.postfilter`. I've updated my answer. The way you use `.filter()` is already right. The problem is the returned data is not an array to loop through.

Comment: thanks Orlandster, would you like to elaborate how to map this, i'm newbie in this.

Comment: I've updated the code above. Make sure to add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'` in order to import the map operator.

Comment: this would help me a lot in updating my apps. i have marked it as answer but i couldn't upvote it as i'm new in this community. cheers n have a great day Orlandster !

Answer (score 0):

"i have included import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'; but still getting error : Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'. how to filter the return json file correctly?"
Because you don't say that data is an array

```
 this.http.get('http://example.com/date.php')
      .subscribe((data:any[]) => { //<--say that you received an array
         this.posts = data;
         //Here filter is filter of an ARRAY, not Rxjs
         this.postsfilter = data.filter(item => item.date == todayDate);
      });
```